# Defining and using a global variable in jquery and combining functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have the jquery code below which I'm using to control aspects of navigation on a responsive website. My questions are:

- is there a way to declare var myWidth as global, so that I don't have to keep repeating it in the code?
- alternatively, is there a way to combine the two $(window).resize functions into one, to make the code less redundant? I tried this and the code no longer worked.
- this script doesn't work in IE8 (but works in IE9 and 10), what could be the cause?

I pieced this code together by researching various jquery questions/answers and tutorials, as I, unfortunately, have no working knowledge of JS or jquery. The code is working as is in all devices/browsers I tested. I do realize that this code is rather redundant, and I would like to request guidance tidying it up a bit.

Thanks in advance!

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#menuHeader').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#mainNav ul").slideToggle(350);
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down2 icon-arrow-up2');
  $('#menuHeader').toggleClass('touchHover');
});

$(window).width(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 650)
$('#mainNav ul').hide();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var myWidth = Math.max( $(window).width(), window.innerWidth);
    if (myWidth > 650)
        $('#mainNav ul').show();
    else 
        $('#mainNav ul').hide();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var myWidth = Math.max( $(window).width(), window.innerWidth);
    if(myWidth > 650)
        $('#menuHeader').removeClass('touchHover');
        $('#menuHeader').find('span').addClass('icon-arrow-down2');
        $('#menuHeader').find('span').removeClass('icon-arrow-up2');

});

});
```

Comment: `window` is already global so no need for creating global var `myWidth`. Can I ask why you cannot simply put the logic into one `$(window).resize` rather than having two?

Comment: When I tried combining the two functions in one $(window).resize, my code didn't work. This is why I'm asking for help - if there's a way to combine this, I'd love to know how!

Comment: Please edit your question and mention that combining the two resizing functions does not work. I'll vote to reopen your question once you've done so.

Comment: I edited to include that information.